# Neo4j - traversal to find specific connected component

Tags: neo4j, traversal, neo4jphp

Using neo4j 1.9.4, I'm trying to find the connected components (all reachable nodes) from a starting node where the relationship has a certain attribute ('*since*') and this attribute has a defined integer value, e.g. *20130101*.

My initial approach was using a cypher query, but I got the feeling that this query loops to infinity if there is a loop within the graph? At least if I do not restrict the path length and restricting the length is not what I want to do.

So meanwhile I started using a traversal. Using neo4jphp a traversal looks like that:

```
$traversal->setOrder(Everyman\Neo4j\Traversal::OrderBreadthFirst)
    ->setPruneEvaluator(Everyman\Neo4j\Traversal::PruneNone)
    ->setReturnFilter(Everyman\Neo4j\Traversal::ReturnAll)
    ->setUniqueness(Everyman\Neo4j\Traversal::UniquenessNodeGlobal);
```

What I think I need is something like this:

```
->setPruneEvaluator('javascript', "position.RELATIONSHIP().getProperty('since').EQUALS(20130101)")
```

Obviously, *RELATIONSHIP* and *EQUALS* seem to be wrong. 
I adopted this from the example https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Traversals, where the following valid and working pruneElevater is set:

```
->setPruneEvaluator('javascript', "position.endNode().getProperty('name').toLowerCase().contains('t')")
```

I'm absolutely not familiar with JavasScript, so I can't figure out how to do that. Additionally, how can I make sure the traversal does not result in an error if there is a relationship that does not have the property "*since*"?
If I can achieve the same using a cypher query I would accept that, too.

**EDIT**: By the way, my approach using cypher was this:

```
START n=node({start_node}) MATCH p = n-[*]-m WHERE ALL(x IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE HAS(x.since) AND x.since = 20130101) RETURN DISTINCT m
```

**EDIT2**: Trying the suggested cypher query from ulkas give me the following error:

```
Invalid query
string matching regex ``(``|[^`])*`' expected but `*' found
Think we should have better error message here? Help us by sending this query to cypher@neo4j.org.
Thank you, the Neo4j Team.
"START n=node(40317) MATCH p = n-[r:*..]-m WHERE has(r.since) AND r.since = 20130101 RETURN DISTINCT m"
                                    ^
```

**EDIT3**: The suggestion of LameCode looked really promising, but still it returns an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Everyman\Neo4j\Exception' with message 'Unable to execute traversal [400]: Headers: Array ( [Content-Length] => 5183 [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8 [Access-Control-Allow-Origin] => * [Server] => Jetty(6.1.25) ) Body: Array ( [message] => Failed to execute script, see nested exception. [exception] => EvaluationException [fullname] => org.neo4j.server.rest.domain.EvaluationException [stacktrace] => Array ( [0] => org.neo4j.server.scripting.javascript.JavascriptExecutor.execute(JavascriptExecutor.java:118) [1] => org.neo4j.server.rest.domain.EvaluatorFactory$ScriptedEvaluator.evalPosition(EvaluatorFactory.java:140) [2] => org.neo4j.server.rest.domain.EvaluatorFactory$ScriptedPruneEvaluator.evaluate(EvaluatorFactory.java:161) [3] => org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.Evaluator$AsPathEvaluator.evaluate(Evaluator.java:69) [4] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraverserIterator.eva in /var/www/vendor/everyman/neo4jphp/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Command.php on line 116
```

And I used the following pruneEvaluator:

```
->setPruneEvaluator('javascript', "position.lastRelationship().hasProperty('since') && position.lastRelationship().getProperty('since') == 20130101")
```

When changing from *lastRelationship()* to *endNode()* it at least doesn't return me an error, despite I am wondering about the many results it returns, as none of the nodes has exactly this since attribute?! So it seems even then, the prune evaluator does not get to work. I expected it to stop at each endNode if has no since property or if it is unqual the given date? What am I doing wrong, any ideas?

Comment: the loop with cypher should not be a problem. maybe modify it like `START n=node({start_node}) MATCH p = n-[r:*..]-m WHERE has(r.since) AND r.since = 20130101 RETURN DISTINCT m`

Comment: Trying this query gives me the following error:

Invalid query

string matching regex ``(``|[^`])*`' expected but `*' found

Think we should have better error message here? Help us by sending this query to cypher@neo4j.org.

Thank you, the Neo4j Team.

     "START n=node(40317) MATCH p = n-[r:*..]-m WHERE has(r.since) AND r.since = 20130101 RETURN DISTINCT m"
                                    ^

Comment: you are right, the `*..` syntax can be used with a specific relationship type only, for whatever reason. right now i can't find any better cypher statement than yours with `where all`. maybe redesign the graph and make each date like `20130101` a node instead of rel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to the Traverser that you are using.  The javascript prune evaluator 'position' variable is a Path object.  See: http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/1.9.4/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Path.html

Those methods should be available to you.

Use `lastRelationship()` (because all the former relationships will have come through the prune evaluator already).

The Relationship object inherits from [Property Container](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/1.9.4/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html) and that has a `hasProperty()` method.

```
setPruneEvaluator('javascript', "position.lastRelationship().hasProperty('since') && position.lastRelationship().getProperty('since') == 20130101")
```

I'm not sure if you need to use the Equals method or not since it's javascript.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, which looks really what I want, but it still returns an error, see my edit above

Comment: It appears that according to the documentation lastRelationship() can return null. And it probably would for the very first path (which I imagine would be just the node by itself).  So try adding in position.lastRelationship() != null && to the beginning.

Comment: That's it! No errors anymore. Though, I am not quite sure if the prune evaluator gets really deployed the way I want it to be. Seems the traversal goes on iterating even though the relationships have a different 'since' attribute. But anyway, thank you for your help